# NetLogo: how to use data from txt file

Tags: list, coordinates, netlogo

I started using Netlogo a few weeks ago and I still have to learn a lot.

I'm writing a model and I need to access 3 values from my excel file to set initial placement of turtles on the world. Values are an x variable, y variable and a type(1,2,3,4). 
I know that I have to convert the file in a txt file but I dont't understand how to organize the values in a list and open it to take them.
I would like to ask each turtle access 'x' and 'y', and populate the screen using this positions, than color turtles according to the type.

I really appreciate any help and suggestions on this matter.

L.

Comment: You can use these predefined functions of NetLogo, let us know what you've tried so far. http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#fileiogroup

Comment: see previous questions such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675239/reading-an-excel-txt-file-with-both-text-and-numbers-into-netlogo?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059067/can-netlogo-read-an-excel-file-format?lq=1 , etc

Comment: see also File Input Example, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library

Comment: Also see this recent question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096948/how-to-read-a-csv-file-with-netlogo

Comment: I saw the examples but the problem is different from mine.. I tried to delete last column (the one with the type) and in this way the code works.
it is:


to setup-cities
  
  file-open "capoluoghi.csv"
    while [not file-at-end?]
  [crt 1 
    [set xcor file-read
      set ycor file-read
    ]
  ]
  file-close
  
end

but in this way it's not useful for me because I need to read also third column. How can I say " read fist column 1-2 and set xycor, than read column 3 and set color?"

Thanks!